# Validar de 1 a 6 dígitos, sendo que o primeiro não pode ser zero

Tags: regex

Como é a regex para validar a seguinte regra:

1. Somente números;
2. No máximo 6 números, e no mínimo 1;
3. O primeiro número precisa ser diferente de 0;

Tentei da seguinte forma e não deu certo:

```
/^[1-9]+(\d){0,5}$/
```

Qual o erro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está no `+` em `[1-9]+`.

O [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", portanto `[1-9]+` pega uma ou mais ocorrências de dígitos de `1` a `9`.

Se quer exatamente um dígito de `1` a `9`, basta remover o `+`:

```
/^[1-9]\d{0,5}$/
```

E repare também que não precisa de parênteses em volta do `\d`, sendo assim, `\d{0,5}` já pega de zero a cinco dígitos de `0` a `9`.

---

Como não foi dito qual linguagem/*engine*/ferramenta você está usando, acho que vale mencionar que o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`, dependendo da linguagem/*engine*/ferramenta, pode considerar também qualquer caractere da [categoria Unicode "Number, Decimal Digit"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). Isto inclui não apenas os dígitos de `0` a `9`, mas também vários outros caracteres que representam dígitos, como por exemplo o `٢` ([ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT TWO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0662/index.htm)), entre outros.

Se a ideia é garantir somente dígitos de `0` a `9`, pode trocar para:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]{0,5}$/
```

Mas claro que se você estiver usando uma *engine* na qual `\d` é equivalente a `[0-9]` (ou se você sabe que seus dados nunca terão os outros caracteres já citados), aí tanto faz usar um ou outro.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!